# AWS cannot remember or paste password

Tags: passwords, amazon-web-services

Hi my AWS remote desktop used to remember the password.

Now it asked for it at the administrator login window. (I'm using a very long password from my company). The problem is I can't copy/paste the password here. 
[image: administrator login asks for password]

I have pasted password at the "edit -> update your credential" windows, but it still asks me for password in the administrator login window (the blue screen). 
[image: i have pasted the password at update your credential]

Is there a way I can make it remember the password, or let me paste it - I prefer to not change to easier password, since it's company account.

Comment: Looking for a solution too. Since this has worked until recently, I suspect it has to do with a recent Windows update messing things up.

Comment: Same to me @Amnon - it used to remember the password at windows login...